# Creating a Dataframe out of several API GET results appended into one single list

Tags: json, pandas, api, dataframe

I have a list with several 16 API GET results appended and i'm struglling into turning them into a dataframe. The raw results looks like this:

['{"total":17,"result":[{"categories":[],"created_at":"2020-01-05 13:42:19.576875","icon_url":"https://assets.chucknorris.host/img/avatar/chuck-norris.png","id":"Tg3Q-ujvSpOXmrrkZUhVHA","updated_at":"2020-01-05 13:42:19.576875","url":"https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/Tg3Q-ujvSpOXmrrkZUhVHA","value":"Chuck Norris believes that Shanimal rocks."},{"categories":[],"created_at":"2020-01-05 13:42:20.568859","icon_url":"https://assets.chucknorris.host/img/avatar/chuck-norris.png","id":"5D6ilY48Q8yoE4_ch_U8Dw","updated_at":"2020-01-05 13:42:20.568859","url":"https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/5D6ilY48Q8yoE4_ch_U8Dw","value":"The Honey Badger (most fearless animal in the Guinness Book of World Records) checks under its bed﻿ every night for Chuck Norris."}, (...)

I'm not being able to get the columns right. It doesn't recognize the keys inside, and it's only allowing me to create 1 column:

```
df_chuck_jokes = pd.DataFrame(response_list, columns=['categories'])
```

[image]

When what i'm looking for is something like this:

[image]

Comment: If your APIs return you a json, you should try the "read_json" function of Pandas instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extension of your earlier post, but now that you've shown the response, modify the original question's answer like this. Instead of creating a list of responses, you can create the 16 dataframes then concatentate.

```
df_list = [] #capture list of dataframes 
for s in list(r.keys()): # replace list(r.keys()) with your list
    querystring = {"query":s}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    print(response.text)
    data = response.text
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(data['result']) #append list of dfs
df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0) #concat the individual dfs to one large df
```

What does data look like?

```
In [614]: data
Out[614]:
{'total': 17,
 'result': [{'categories': [],
   'created_at': '2020-01-05 13:42:19.576875',
   'icon_url': 'https://assets.chucknorris.host/img/avatar/chuck-norris.png',
   'id': 'Tg3Q-ujvSpOXmrrkZUhVHA',
   'updated_at': '2020-01-05 13:42:19.576875',
   'url': 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/Tg3Q-ujvSpOXmrrkZUhVHA',
   'value': 'Chuck Norris believes that Shanimal rocks.'},
  {'categories': [],
   'created_at': '2020-01-05 13:42:20.568859',
   'icon_url': 'https://assets.chucknorris.host/img/avatar/chuck-norris.png',
   'id': '5D6ilY48Q8yoE4_ch_U8Dw',
   'updated_at': '2020-01-05 13:42:20.568859',
   'url': 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/5D6ilY48Q8yoE4_ch_U8Dw',
   'value': 'The Honey Badger (most fearless animal in the Guinness Book of World Records) checks under its bed\ufeff every night for Chuck Norris.'}]}
```

what does each of the 16 dfs look like?

```
In [615]: pd.DataFrame(data['result'])
Out[615]:
  categories                  created_at                                           icon_url  ...                  updated_at                                                url                                              value
0         []  2020-01-05 13:42:19.576875  https://assets.chucknorris.host/img/avatar/chu...  ...  2020-01-05 13:42:19.576875  https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/Tg3Q-ujvSpOXm...         Chuck Norris believes that Shanimal rocks.
1         []  2020-01-05 13:42:20.568859  https://assets.chucknorris.host/img/avatar/chu...  ...  2020-01-05 13:42:20.568859  https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/5D6ilY48Q8yoE...  The Honey Badger (most fearless animal in the ...

[2 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: hi, thanks again for the great help. i'm getting an error on the last line --  File "<ipython-input-13-5ea2eb55a866>", line 16
    df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0) #concat the individual dfs to one large df
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: if i run it without the final line where the large df is going to be concatenated, i get --   File "<ipython-input-14-4a8b1984ebfe>", line 16
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(data['result']) #append list of dfs
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: if i run it without the 2 final lines it does iterate and get the values from the API but the df_list will be empty without them

Comment: Looks like I'm missing a close parentheses on the append line. Please check that as I wasn't able to fully test.

Comment: you're absolutely right. but still getting an error appending the DFs ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-9cdc0e6f2ad8> in <module>
     16     print(response.text)
     17     data = response.text
---> 18     df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(data['result'])) #append list of dfs
     19 df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0) #concat the individual dfs to one large df

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: You're going to have to play around with how the response gets into the data frame. Maybe data = response.text is incorrect. Some other minor parsing may need to be there.

Comment: yes. i'm testing. will keep updated once i am successful (thanks for your help!)

Answer (score 0):

The full code (that would not be possible without @jonathan-leon great help):

First we get the jokes categories:

```
import requests

url = "https://matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com/jokes/categories"

headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "xxxx",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
r = response.json() # using json to transform the requested data into a class list
```

Turn it into a dataframe. This might not be needed but as i'm starting out i find it easier to work with DFs:

```
df_chuck_categories = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=['category'])
```

Now we go back to the API and request all of the categories information. I tweaked the earlier response by changing the response to json:

```
import requests

url = "https://matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com/jokes/search"
headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "xxxx",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "matchilling-chuck-norris-jokes-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    }                  

df_list = [] #capture list of dataframes
for s in list(df_chuck_categories['category']): # replace list(r.keys()) with your list
    querystring = {'query':s}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
#   print(response.text) # uncomment to check if requests is working
    data = response.json()
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(data['result'])) #append list of dfs
    df_chuck_jokes = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0) #concat the individual dfs to one large df
```

And finally we just reset the index so that it counts sequentially from start to finish

```
df_chuck_jokes = df_chuck_jokes.reset_index(drop=True)
```